# What are some other ways this loop can be rewritten?

Tags: raku

Got this simple loop:

```
use Config::Simple:from<Perl5>;

my $cfg = Config::Simple.new(syntax => 'ini');


%config{'short_name'} = 'blah';
for %config.kv -> $k, $v {
    $cfg.param("%config{'short_name'}.$k", $v);
}
```

Works fine. But I want to get more familiar with other ways to achieve the same goal, if only to get comfortable reading other people's code. Plus, loops seem to be the "old" school way of doing things and not very "Raku-like" and I need to get more comfortable working with using functions in more advanced ways.

Anyway, to stretch my new Raku muscles, I came up with this one-liner as an alternative:

```
map(-> $k, $v { $cfg.param("%config{'short_name'}.$k", $v) }, %config.kv);
```

It's less readable (at least to my untrained eye), but it works.

My hunch is there is some good way of making this code both more concise and readable. Interested in seeing if I might be right.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- rewritten (IMHO, `for` is more suitable than `map`, if a variable is changed)

  ```raku
      use Config::Simple:from<Perl5>;

      my $cfg = Config::Simple.new: syntax => 'ini';
      my %config := short_name => 'blah';

      $cfg.param: "%config<short_name>\.{.key}", .value  for %config;

      print $cfg.as_string();
  ```
- by `set_block`

  ```raku
      use Config::Simple:from<Perl5>;

      my $cfg = Config::Simple.new: syntax => 'ini';
      my %config = short_name => 'blah';

      $cfg.set_block: %config<short_name>, %config;

      print $cfg.as_string();
  ```

Comment: Wow, cool. I'm seeing some new syntax in that first block of code. Very interesting. Thanks. And it looks like I missed set_block in the Simple::Config docs. Double thanks.